# Restricting input to have a single hyphen (-) for textbox in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am currently trying to make a calculator in C# which accepts data from two textboxs and perform operations on them. I am having a problem dealing with negative values specifically restricting textbox to have just a single hyphen at start. This is the code I have tried but if I delete the hyphen using backspace than I cannot put it back again.

```
    bool neg = false;
    private void val2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 127 && ch != 46 && ch != 45)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (ch == 46)
        {
            if (pnt2 == true)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            pnt2 = true;
        }
        else if (ch == 45)
        {
            if (neg == true)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            neg = true;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using windows form or webform?

Comment: I am using windows form.

Comment: What's the purpose of pnt2 and neg?

Comment: They are actually characters,pnt2 is supposed to restrict input to only have a single decimal point in textbox and i was using the same technique with hyphen with neg. Since Sergy have shown me another way so I will be using it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your control text. If it contains hyphen - don't allow another one.

```
if(val2.Text.Contains("-"))
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

If you want to allow hyphen only as a first character do the following:

```
if(val2.Text.Length > 0)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Well well you saved the day sir, Thank you once again! :)